# How to make kendoui angular2 chartcomponent as donutchart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Can any one please help me to make the chart component of kendoui angular2

as donut chart

i'm able to gt the chart by  following the example in this page http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/ but how to make it as donut chart

Thanks&Rds,
Raghu S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample template for a Donut Chart

```
    <kendo-chart>
      <kendo-chart-title text="Donut Chart"></kendo-chart-title>
      <kendo-chart-series-defaults type="donut">
      </kendo-chart-series-defaults>
      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="seriesData">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
```

You can test it in this Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nvOfXk7VGhOl2f4esCfL?p=preview

Comment: yaa thanks for help its working for me. Can you help me to to show labels/Legends and where i should look for all these properties of the chart

Comment: This article shows how to configure the different parts of the Chart:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/structure/

Comment: iam getting the donut chart but not able to achieve legends for donut chart can anyone help

Comment: I know this is rather old but you dont add the type in the `kendo-chart-series-defaults` tag, you add it in the `kendo-chart-series-item` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-chart>
          <kendo-chart-title text="Simple Donut Chart">
          </kendo-chart-title>
          <kendo-chart-series-defaults type="donut">
          </kendo-chart-series-defaults>
          <kendo-chart-legend position="top">
          </kendo-chart-legend>
          <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="seriesData">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
          </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
    `
})
class AppComponent {
    private seriesData = [[4,"1st"],[7,"2nd"],[5,"3rd"]];
}
```

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/86dA5xCCSxatBOmapnGo?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="donut"` with your `kendo-chart-series-item` tag.